# How i can change the icon in the Icon button

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I am trying to build a whatsapp clone and when I was working on the changing the camera from front and back. I was trying to change the Icon in the Icon button but it was not changing

I will attach my code file below

```
    Widget bottomIcon({Icon icon,double size,Function onpress}){
        return IconButton(
          icon: icon,
          iconSize: size,
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: onpress,
        );
      }
    
    Icon iconForcam=Icon(Icons.camera_rear);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
          return Container();
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                 CameraPreview(controller),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                      bottomIcon(icon: Icon(Icons.flash_on_rounded),size: 50.0),
                      SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                      bottomIcon(icon: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record_outlined),size: 100.0),
                      SizedBox(width: 30.0,),
                      bottomIcon(icon: iconForcam,size: 50.0,onpress: (){
                        setState(() {
                          if(iconForcam == Icon(Icons.camera_front)){
    
                            iconForcam = Icon(Icons.camera_rear);
                          }else if(iconForcam == Icon(Icons.camera_rear)){
                            print('rearcam');
                            iconForcam = Icon(Icons.camera_front);
                          }
                        });
                        //toggleCamera();
                      }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      }
```

I have the doubt that in the if I can comapre two icons in the if Statement.

Comment: Do you use StatefulWidget? setState(() { iconForcam = Icon(Icons.camera_rear); });

Comment: yeah but i need to change it back and forth for every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a boolean variable

//Define

```
bool _isFront = true;
```

//Usage

```
bottomIcon(
  icon: _isFront ? 
      Icons.camera_front : Icons.camera_rear, 
  size: 50.0, onpress: (){
      setState(() {
        _isFront = !_isFront;
      });
      //toggleCamera();
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro I tried this and that works fine bro

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and got that correct

//Defint

```
    int _oldIndex=0;
    Icon iconForcam=Icon(Icons.camera_rear);
```

//Inside code

```
    bottomIcon(icon: iconForcam,size: 50.0,onpress: (){
                        setState(() {
                          if(_oldIndex == 0){
                            iconForcam = Icon(Icons.camera_rear);
                            _oldIndex = 1;
                          }else if(_oldIndex == 1){
                            //print('rearcam');
                            iconForcam = Icon(Icons.camera_front);
                            _oldIndex = 0;
                          }
                        });
                        toggleCamera(_oldIndex);
                      }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store whether the front camera is on or not in shared_prefernces or database, use provider/stream/bloc to expose this value to UI. Now you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_icon) to change icon with animation. Install this package to your flutter project, import it in the file, and then replace `icon` property of the camera button with the below code:

```
AdvancedIcon(
  icon: Icons.camera_front,
  secondaryIcon: Icons.camera_rear,
  state: isFrontCameraOn ? AdvancedIconState.primary : AdvancedIconState.secondary,
)
```

Now the icon will automatically change depending on whether the front camera is on or not.

If you have problem with the database or provider part of this question just let me know.